Custom TextField/Button: presents search view
I am trying to create a simple view  but learning SwiftUI has been a challenge.
Using SwiftUI I am trying to create a view that has a Textfield/Button combo, where when clicked it will present a search bar and allow the user to search for an airport using their ICAO ID such as KLAX or KJFK. After they have selected an airport, I'd like the title of that button to become that airport ICAO ID.
I already have a large portion of the JSON handling/request done and coded, but I am mostly stumped on SwiftUI. I tried using the .searchable() but I can't figure out how I can activate .searchable() upon a button action.
I also want to add a view that will filter the results as you are searching.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedHomeAirport = [Airport]()
    
    @State private var homeAirport: String = "KCMA"
    @State private var searchedAirport: String = ""
    
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    // "https://aviationweather.gov/cgi-bin/data/metar.php?ids=KVNY&hours=0&order=id%2C-obs&sep=true&elev&format=json"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text(homeAirport)
            }
            .task {
                NavigationStack {
                    ContentView().searchable(text: $searchedAirport, prompt: "Search Airport")
                }
            }

            
//            Button {
//                print("enter new airport")
//                
//            } action: {
//                
//            } label: {
//                Text("\(homeAirport)")
//            }
//            .task {
//                // airports
//            }
//            .searchable(text: $searchedAirport, prompt: "Search Airport")
//            
//            .font(.headline)
//            .foregroundColor(.green)
            //.position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
            //.position(y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
        }
    }
            
    func loadData() async {
        // Load Data from URL
        let acwURL = "https://aviationweather.gov/cgi-bin/data/metar.php?ids=\(homeAirport)&hours=0&order=id%2C-obs&sep=true&elev&format=json"
        // create url
        guard let url = URL(string: acwURL) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        // fetch url and data
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let decoded: [Airport] = try JSONDecoder().decode([Airport].self, from: data)
            selectedHomeAirport = decoded
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

So I am getting closer was able to get here, but the only issues is I just want the search bar to toggle, not for an entire sheet, to pull up, any suggestions for getting around this?
            Button(action: {
                self.showingDetail.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(homeAirport)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                    .fontDesign(.monospaced)
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                CustomSearchBar(searchText: $searchedAirport)
            }


Please show some code and point out exactly where you are stuck at.

Posted but, Im just on the initial implementation. How do i get the .searchable() to activate only when the user click the button

You mean you want the search bar to appear after clicking a button? Or do you mean you want the search text field to be focused after clicking on a button?

Hmm. I would say the first, the search bar appearing after clicking a button. So i guess a textfield would not be needed?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76919885/5133585 or just make your own search bar like I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76832590/5133585

ah thank you looking over them. so with your solution would i call the .toolbar {} on the button in order to have it activate only when the button is clicked?
